# Java - two chars, how recognize which one is '?'

Tags: java

I have two char '�' and '?'.
How to recognize them from java?
How to check which one is natural '?' and which one is not?

Comment: `'?'` is equal to `'?'` (e.g. `c == '?'` would be true), the other one is not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove special and 4 bytes char from String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69538807/how-to-remove-special-and-4-bytes-char-from-string)

Answer (score 1):

---

**Character Encoding:**

Short: In computers, each character is represented by a set of binary digits. The digits for representing a character are determined by the ***character encoding*** that you have chosen to use. For enrichment:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding

---

**Solution:**

To the two characters you've introduced here, there are completely different numeric values. I don't know what character encoding you are using (I don't need to know), so try to print their numeric value by converting them to an integer and look at the result.

As you can see, their values are different, and incidentally, also their appearance. Therefore, it follows that all that needs to be done is to compare these two characters (Which is actually to compare both numeric values).

```
if ('�' == '?')
    System.out.println("Always False!");
```

Can you see the problem here? Yes, this condition will be always **FALSE**. As a result, the instruction inside the *if statement* scope is considered **dead code**.

Comment: So i will add more info. I make tests:

Test 1:
char c1 = '?';

char c2 = '?';

if(c1 == c2){
    System.out.println("false");
}

Result: false


Test2:

char c1 = '?';

char c2 = '�';

if(c1 == c2){
    System.out.println("false");
}

Result: false

Test3:

char c1 = '?';

char c2 = '�';

System.out.println("int value of c1 = "+(int)c1);

System.out.println("int value of c2 = "+(int)c2);

Result:

int value of c1 = 63

int value of c2 = 63

Comment: System.out.println((int) '�' + " " + (int) '?'); Try to run this and tell me the result.